# webElement.getText() как забрать нужный элемент

Tags: java, selenium

Пишу автотест, который проверяет некое поле на сайте, на соответствие.
Все работает нормально, но: обычно обращаюсь к какому-либо элементу и через `randomelement.getText();` забираю текст.

Возникла проблема, что в моем случае нужный мне текст(не в теге) находится в `div`, и помимо этого текста, есть другие строки, заключенные в теги(все это находится в вышеупомянутом `div`).

В итоге вылезает не "1 шт." , а например: "Ваша книга: 1 шт. Название книги."

Вопрос: можно как-то попробовать выудить только "1 шт."?

Текст проверяю через - `assertEquals(radndomElement.getText(), "1 шт.");`

Использую: *Java*, *Selenium*, *TestNg*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем посмотрел по ссылке, у них был такой код:

```
public static String geNodeText(WebElement element) {
    String text = element.getText();
    for (WebElement child : element.findElements(By.xpath("./*"))) {
      text = text.replaceFirst(child.getText(), "");
    }
    return text;
  }
```

Код работает, но в моем случае он выдает это в виде:

```
1 строка
2 строка 
3 строка
```

Сделал свой вариант:

```
public static String geNodeTextSec(WebElement element,int startStringPoint,int endStringPoint) {
    String text = element.getAttribute("innerText").trim().replaceAll("\\n", ""); // Весь текст перегоняем в одну строку
    String newText = text.substring(startStringPoint,endStringPoint); // Выбираем нужный нам отрезок
        return newText;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант попробуйте:

1. получит список вложенных тегов
2. получить текст из каждого вложенного тега
3. удалить из основного текста содержимое каждого вложенного тега.

Comment: Да, неплохой вариант. Но немного подержу открытым вопрос, может кто знает еще другой метод)

Comment: Похоже это сами selenium'овцы и используют - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/3mbMXA3sdlA (в самом конце заапрувленный кусок кода)

Comment: @MikitaBerazouski, да и вправду.